# How to configure different aws credentials for Kinesis streams with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I have two Kinesis streams that I need to consume but they have different credentials.

In issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/issues/74 it says: "...The difference in the configuration properties is achieved with the environment property where you can configure different cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey and cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey..."

So I made **application.properties** file that looks like this:

```
# Spring Cloud - Input1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.destination=example1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.group=test-kinesis-stream-group1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.binder=kinesisConsumer1

# Spring Cloud - Input2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2.destination=example2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2.group=test-kinesis-stream-group2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2.binder=kinesisConsumer2


# Kinesis
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled=true
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.bindings.input.consumer.listener-mode=batch
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.bindings.input.consumer.idle-between-polls=200

# BINDERS1
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kinesisConsumer1.type=kinesis
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kinesisConsumer1.default-candidate=false
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kinesisConsumer1.inherit-environment=true
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kinesisConsumer1.environment.cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID1}
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kinesisConsumer1.environment.cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY1}

# BINDERS2
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kinesisConsumer2.type=kinesis
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kinesisConsumer2.default-candidate=false
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kinesisConsumer2.inherit-environment=false
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kinesisConsumer2.environment.cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID2}
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kinesisConsumer2.environment.cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY2}
```

But then I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'cloudWatchClient' must not be null` exception. Even when I try example with listening to only one stream it stops working when I add `environment.cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey` and `environment.cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey` properties.

Do I need to configure this environment property differently? Am I maybe missing configuring some property in **application.properties** file or in class that implements @StreamListener.

My consumers work perfectly fine when I use them in separate applications with usual way of giving aws credentials, but once I add `environment.cloud.aws`they stop working with above excpetion even when I try to run them separately.

Comment: May we see the whole stack trace on the matter? The issue you mention has been fixed long time ago for the regular Kinesis client. The KCL support has been added later, so we probably may miss something distributive around that `cloudWatchClient` bean... So, more info from the exception would be useful.

Comment: Sorry for late response, here is stacktrace https://pastebin.com/avxmCsZm